# Can I test windows 7 on a virtual PC?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc

Is there anywhere to download windows 7 to test on a virtual PC?

I have Windows XP now and I don't want to install the upgrade yet but wanted to just play around.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can still [download the Release Candidate](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/get/download.aspx) free. Works fine in a virtual machine.

- download VirtualBox from [virtualbox.org](http://www.virtualbox.org/)
- download the Windows 7 ISO from the above link.
- after installing VirtualBox, create a New VM for Windows 7, make sure it has access to the minimum requirements from your system:

*1 GHz or faster 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x64) processor
*1 GB RAM (32-bit) / 2 GB RAM (64-bit)
*16 GB available disk space (32-bit) / 20 GB (64-bit)
*DirectX 9 graphics processor with WDDM 1.0 or higher driver

- Go to the configuration settings for your new virtual machine, and access the CD-ROM settings.
- Select the radio button to boot from existing ISO file and choose your Windows 7 ISO.
- follow installation instructions and you'll be up and running in no time.

Comment: i am a little confused.  maybe i have a more fundamental question on how i would go about setting up a virtual machine to run this on?

Comment: Annoying that Microsoft provides a ready-to-run VHD of Server 2008 R2 RC - but not for Windows 7 RC... that would have made it much easier.

Answer (score 1):

I test it with virtual Box. Just download the W7 install ISO and install it to a new VM.

Comment: how do you install it to a new VM?

Comment: http://blogs.sun.com/fatbloke/entry/windows_7_on_virtualbox

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install Windows 7 (either the RC or the RTM version) in a virtual machine. I currently have the RC running as the primary OS on two of my systems, one of which also has Virtual Box running a Windows 7 RC VM to test Visual Studio 2010.